# How is this UI called (multiple pages with settings, dots on bottom marks progress, usually after install of app)

Tags: layout, terminology, css, concept

On mobile phone when I install some app it shows few pages with basic settings, at the bottom are dots indicating progress, sometimes back/next button. How is this thing called? I want to find and try existing css solutions, but I can't find it because I don't know proper name.

First page

```
+-----------------+
|     Welcome     |
|                 |
|                 |
| Lorem ipsum...  |
|                 |
|                 |
|      o---  Next |
+-----------------+
```

Second page

```
+-----------------+
|      Email      |
|                 |
|                 |
| [@            ] |
|                 |
|                 |
| Back oo--  Next |
+-----------------+
```

Third page:

```
+-----------------+
|  News settings  |
|                 |
| [x] foo         |
| [ ] bar         |
|                 |
|                 |
| Back ooo-  Next |
+-----------------+
```

Last page

```
+-----------------+
|  All done       |
|                 |
| Blah bla        |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
| Back oooo Finish|
+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**Wizard**

At least that's what you call it on desktop.

Example: https://gytis.co.uk/case-study/mobile-wizard-design-pattern-ux-case-study/

Answer (score 0):

It's called a "walkthrough" or a "tutorial", which usually appears when a user launches the app for the first time. It's either a series of full-screen images or an overlay screen that points out the functions of different parts of an app.

Eg: https://www.pinterest.com/samara0306/app-tutorialwalkthrough/

Comment: Could you expand on this answer?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of answer you were expecting? The question is a simple one and requires a simple answer.